How would someone of Miles’s age say those words?
After meeting Miles’s parents, Gwen left abruptly due
to duty calls, leaving Miles disappointed:

Miles: I can hear you being quiet, Mom.
Rio: I, um... hope I didn't ice your game, man.
Miles: No one my age says those words in that order, Mom.

How would someone of Miles’s age say those words?

I suspect he means those words would be used in different sentences, in any order, rather than put together in a sentence like Mom did. In context, Miles is annoyed with his Mom, because she's trying to use young-person slang but has either invented something that nobody ever used, or is using slang that is younger than her, but is still way out of date for him (and he doesn't care which).
P.S. What she means is clear in context - she hopes she didn't do something that led Gwen to leave abruptly
